# Fix image on Safari browser

Tags: css, xhtml, safari

I use Safari to browse the net, i need to display an image as the background, my problem is that i want the image to be fixed and the text still scrollable.
My code that doesn't work is this :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type=text/css>
body{background-image:url('background.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>My text goes here</body>
</html>
```

with this code, i have both the image and the text scrollable.

Comment: I can only disagree. The image is fixed. Add something like `html {height: 200%;}` to the css to check that.

Comment: Works for me in Safari 5.0.5. The bg image is on the screen all the time while the text is scrollable. Isn't it what you need to get?

Comment: @spliter : well, yes, that what i need to get, however, the image isn't in the always on the screen :(

Comment: Have you got a live example @Malek? Your code looks like it should work absolutely fine.

Comment: @Thaddee Tyi : your suggestion doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @jack Franklin : the live example is the Safari Browser of my iPhone, i will see if i could put screenshots :)

Comment: Ahhh it's in the iPhone Safari! Wish you'd said that originally, that changes things. Not entirely sure if mobile Safari supports `fixed` backgrounds, will have a look.

Comment: @Malek see my edit on my question now, mobile Safari doesn't support `fixed` but will in IOS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what's going on, as your code looks fine. Maybe you don't actually want it `fixed`? `Fixed` means the image wont move at all as you scroll, is that what you want?

I set up a JSFiddle which works fine. The only thing I did differently is declare all the info in the shorthand `background` property:

```
body {
    background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-xpgIOttwTTg/TWRni-cC-tI/AAAAAAAAA-o/9GMqFyMnQCY/s1600/african-elephant2.jpg) repeat fixed;
}
```

And the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jackfranklin/HYagh/

Checked & it works fine in Safari.

EDIT - now I know you're talking about Mobile Safari, `position:fixed` AND `background-attachment:fixed;` is **not** supported in iOS Safari up to iOS4, however is **is** supported in the upcoming iOS5.

Comment: Thanx for clarification Jack, would you say `background-attachment:fixed;` or `position:fixed` or both ?

Comment: I mean both, apologies for being a bit unclear. I'll edit my post.